# Generating (or Obtaining) the 3D Mesh (Boundary or Element) from an Anatomy3D Image

Tags: mesh, anatomyplot3d

I would like to get a 3D mesh of an organ, let us say the right adrenal gland, for use in NDSolveValue for solving a series of pdes. My question here focuses on obtaining the mesh from the 3D image. The image can be obtained by:

```
img = AnatomyPlot3D[
   Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightAdrenalGland"]];
```

I have tried to use `ImageMesh[img]`to obtain the 3D mesh, however, the output is 2D (despite the documentation indicating that ImageMesh is capable of providing 3D meshes for 3D images) and incorrectly identifies part of the organ as background (output shown below).

[image: Graphic of ImageMesh output]

Alternatively, I have also tried using `ClusteringComponents[img,2]` with the assumption that the resulting 2 components will be background and the adrenal gland, however, the output is superficially 3D (`Head[ClusteringComponents[img,2]//Colorize]` is `Image3D`) but the output is essentially a 2D image (which I presume cannot be used to construct a 3D mesh) and also incorrectly identifies part of the organ as equivalent to the background (shown below).

[image: Output of ClusteringComponents[img,2]//Colorize]

In light of the above, is there a way to generate a 3D mesh from the AnatomyPlot3D image OR a way to obtain an already constructed mesh ( I add this part as running `AnatomyData[ Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightAdrenalGland"], "RegionBounds"]` outputs `{{-62.534, -30.63}, {-102.34, -75.106}, {1045.5, 1087.8}}` as the x, y, and z region bounds which I understand to mean a mesh could already exist and then just needs to be accessed. Thank you in advance for any and all assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd need to use

```
DiscretizeGraphics[img]
```

[image]

because AnatomyPlot3D returns a Graphics3D and not a 3D image.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution - I seem to have just missed this function entirely. Much appreciated. I have marked this as the solution.

Comment: @Joel, out of curiosity, what type of PDE do you want to solve?

Comment: I plan to solve a diffusion style pde (so Laplacian)

Answer (score 4):

We can get a mesh through a built in property:

```
Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightAdrenalGland"]["MeshRegion"]
```

[image]

or equivalently

```
AnatomyData["RightAdrenalGland", "MeshRegion"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it seems I got fixated on going straight to the 3D image (actually graphic as pointed out in the accepted answer) and working to the mesh from there (and bypassed this entirely). Thanks again for the answer.